# NOT EXISTS with table records

Tags: sql

Subtracting the tables seq and article. seq table has 4 matching records of seq '3' and article table has 3 matching records of seqid '3'. I want to subtract the article table from seq table (4-3 = 1). The output returns only one record.

```
SEQ 
id  seq
9    3
11   3
12   4
13   3
16   4
19   3 

article 
id  seqid  article
 6    3    HR Skills
 7    6    Finance 
 9    4    IT
12    3    HR Skills
15    3    HR Skills

SELECT s.id, s.seq, a.article 
FROM seq s 
INNER JOIN article a ON s.seq = a.seqid 
WHERE s.seq NOT EXISTS (select seqid from article);
```

When I execute the query, it returns all the matching records from both the tables. I wanted the query to subtract (4-3 = 1).

Output: (4-3 =1)

```
s.id s.seq a.seqid   a.article
 13    3      3      HR Skills
```

Comment: Any preference of the record to be returned from seq table?
For eg. the record with the highest id

Comment: Subtract is probably the wrong word, it is not clear what you want to do here. I get the impression that you want to select one row from the `seq` table that doesn’t exists in the `article` table, is that correct? How do we determine which row that is? Maybe you could add expected output to your question and an explanation on the logic to find the correct row

Comment: @Ashish. No preference, but only looking for the records from seq table by subtracting

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Exactly, I want the rows that do not exists in article table. I try to correct the word subtract

Comment: Then you need to tell us how to identify them, there is currently not enough information in the question to answer your question

Comment: @JoakimDanielson. I clearly explained my requirement.

Comment: No you haven't which can be seen from the answers you have gotten so far.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson No I'm not. I try to edit the code right now.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just about the count, you could do something like -

```
SELECT s.seq, 
(COUNT(1) - (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM article WHERE seqid = s.seq) AS difference,
(SELECT article FROM article WHERE seqid = s.seq LIMIT 1) AS article
FROM seq s 
GROUP BY s.seq
```

This way you get the difference for all the seq

Comment: the difference is correct, but I don't want the count, I want to pull out the s.seq and a.article. Could you suggest me a better answer.

Comment: Now the query above gives you article too

Comment: It throws an exception, Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Comment: Yeah, it will, as there are multiple records. Either use GROUP BY in the second subquery or use LIMIT 1 to just get one record.

Answer (score 0):

**Query**:

```
 select seqcnt.cnt ,articlecnt.cnt,  isnull(seqcnt.cnt,0) - isnull(articlecnt.cnt,0) subtract  , article. article
    from 
    (select distinct seq , count(seq) cnt from seq  group by seq ) seqcnt
    left join (select distinct seqid , count(seqid) cnt from  article   group by seqid ) articlecnt on seqcnt.seq =  articlecnt.seqid 
    left join (select distinct seqid , article  from  article) article on article. seqid = seqcnt.seq
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: you can add feild seqcnt.seq to get seq.